# c program (linux): get command line output to a variable and filter data

Tags: c, command-line, variable-assignment

i have a c program that runs following command:

```
system("sudo grep '' /sys/class/dmi/id/board_*")
```

and give output on command line.

I want the output to be stored in some variable in c program, so that i can filter `board_serial`.

Comment: Are you really using `grep '' /sys/class/dmi/id/board_*`? Or did you intentionally leave out your search string? If that's really what you're doing, `cat /sys/class/dmi/id/board_*` would be better. Or better yet, just `fopen()` each file (although you would have to handle the wildcard bit yourself then, which is one "benefit" of using the `system()` approach).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html). Here is a simple example of how you could use it to capture the program output:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *p;
    p = popen("ls -l", "r");

    if(!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening pipe.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(!feof(p)) {
        printf("%c", fgetc(p));
    }

    if (pclose(p) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr," Error!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, it looks like you just want to read some value from a file, am I right? I would prefer to just open ([`fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)) the files which have the values inside and read those values to variables in my C program. Try something like this (just a simple example):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char result[MAX];
    int i;
    char c;

    fp = fopen("/sys/class/dmi/id/board_name", "r");

    if(!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    i = 0;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        result[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    result[i] = '\0';

    printf("%s", result);
    i = atoi(result);
    printf("%d", i);

    if (fclose(fp) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr," Error closing file!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to redirect the  output to a file and the read that file for parsing the output.

```
system("sudo grep '' /sys/class/dmi/id/board_* 1>out.txt 2>err.txt");
fd_out = fopen("out.txt", "r");
fd_err = fopen("err.txt", "r");
```

Or you can use `popen` function.

```
fd_out = popen("sudo grep '' /sys/class/dmi/id/board_*", "r");
```

Comment: IMHO, the best approach to this question is to open the file with `fopen()` and simply read its contents to a variable. It looks like the user just wants to read a file.

Answer (score 0):

Use dup or dup2 to duplicate standart output fd to a file fd

[Man dup/dup2](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup.2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes popen is definitely the best choice. Have a look here

```
       http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html
```

Comment: It looks like the user just needs to read a file content. Checking the files in which contents she is interested in, it is just a single line, with a simple string inside.